# Square brackets in the name attribute of input and select tag. Still used?

Tags: html, arrays, select, brackets

After a quick search and struggling to find information about the use of square brackets in the name attribute of input and select tags with the intent of building an array from them on form sending. I found only 2 mentions about this in questions from more then 10 year old. So is this way of getting an array is still relevant in nowadays or their is better alternatives?

Comment: The square bracket syntax is not a 'standard' web tech, but it's just a convention that causes some server-side tech to treat it as an array. I think PHP introduced it, but not every server-side technology will support it (so test it).